# Problem creating extension method for HTMLHelper ('TextBoxFor' is not a member of 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(Of TModel)')

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following extension method that I've built and have working for one MVC3 project, but when trying to use it in another, the *compiler* (not the view) gives me the error;

```
Error   1   'TextBoxFor' is not a member of 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(Of TModel)'...
```

Intellisense shows none of these html element shorcut methods.

I'm sure it's just because I'm missing a reference or something, but beats me what it is.

```
FImports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module HtmlHelperExtension

<Extension()> _
Public Function WatermarkedTextBoxFor(Of TModel, TProperty)(ByVal htmlHelper As System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(Of TModel), ByVal expression As Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty)), ByVal htmlAttributes As IDictionary(Of String, Object)) As MvcHtmlString

    Dim propertyMetaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData)

    Return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, New RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) From {
                                 {"class", "jq_watermark"},
                                 {"title", If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyMetaData.Watermark), propertyMetaData.Watermark, propertyMetaData.GetDisplayName())}
                             })

End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Got it! - Need to import the System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to import the System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace